# Limit of the sum of the series

Tags: real-analysis, laurent-series, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\sqrt{1+ \frac{ k}{n^2}}-1\right)$$
I was trying to use Riemann integral method here, but how to find $f(x)$?
Any hints?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the limit of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{k}{n^2}}-1\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/532404/find-the-limit-of-sum-limits-k-1n-left-sqrt1-frackn2-1-right)

Comment: @Atticus thank you, this was very helpful